# Where to put <meta name="theme-color"> in GoogleSite

Tags: pagespeed, google-sites, google-pagespeed

I want to put `<meta name="theme-color">` to make more progressive web appin GoogleSite. Where to put it?

https://sites.google.com

Answer (score 0):

You must put this tag in the `<head></head>`section of your website, because it is a meta element.
To read more about meta elements, you can follow [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element)

Comment: It seems that Google Sites does not allow the ability to edit the `<head></head>` section : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/h-A_nQwfd1Y

Comment: Thats why I asked.